# GraphQL-java query timeout

Tags: graphql-java

Is there a way to set a timeout on query execution with the GraphQL-java implementation? That seems like a fairly basic security thing that's recommended by the GraphQL [docs](https://www.howtographql.com/advanced/4-security/), but I can't find anything for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GraphQL Java [instrumentation](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v11/instrumentation/) for that.

The example bellow sets a timeout of 3 seconds for every data fetcher. 
You can use the instance of `InstrumentationFieldFetchParameters` passed in to apply the timeout to specific data fetchers (maybe one up on the query structure if you want a timeout for the whole query).

```
public class TimeoutInstrumentation extends SimpleInstrumentation {
    @Override
    public DataFetcher<?> instrumentDataFetcher(
            DataFetcher<?> dataFetcher, InstrumentationFieldFetchParameters parameters
    ) {
        return environment ->
            Observable.fromCallable(() -> dataFetcher.get(environment))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .timeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .blockingFirst();
    }
}
```

You can also use 2 existing instrumentations to achieve other checks mentioned in the page you've posted:

- [MaxQueryComplexityInstrumentation](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/analysis/MaxQueryComplexityInstrumentation.java)
- [MaxQueryDepthInstrumentation](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/analysis/MaxQueryDepthInstrumentation.java)

There's also the option of setting up a timeout at the request level. This is out of GraphQL Java's jurisdiction though. If you're using Spring as the http server you can setup a global request timeout using the `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` application property. I'm pretty sure any other web server would have a similar property as well.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the tips! I'll be implementing that soon.